# Propiedad para digitar todo en mayúscula dentro de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, grid

como puedo hacer para que al momento de ingresar datos dentro de un DataGridView, todos sean en mayúscula por defecto, existe alguna propiedad?

Nota: Tener en cuenta que en mi DataGridView tengo columnas con ComboBox, puse el siguiente código pero me da error al seleccionar un dato en la columna del ComboBox:

```
private void dgvVinculados_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = ((DataGridView)sender);

            TextBox tb = ((TextBox)dgv.EditingControl);

            if (dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                tb.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
            }
            else
            {
                tb.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias aplicar la conversion controlando la columna donde aplicas el `upper` entonces sabes que esa columna seran todas textbox

```
private void dgvVinculados_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        TextBox tb = ((TextBox)e.Control);
        tb.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
    }

}
```

Sino la alternativa es convertir pero sin que falle usando el `as`

```
private void dgvVinculados_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
    }

}
```

asi puedes validar si es null entonces no es un textbox, esto aplicara a todas las celdas del grid

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Leandro Tuttini, el segundo ejemplo me sirvió, lo máximo.